# How To connect the MySQL Database from jsp with my webserver

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

I am using this in a local system

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname", "userid", "password");
```

both are working properly.  But when I am trying to connect with server with this

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname", "userid", "password");
```

It is not working.. !
Database username and password are all correct So how can I connect to my database server.Can anybody post the solution ??

Comment: describe the problem. What problem you are facing. Any exception or what?

Comment: So where's the difference between the two?

Comment: Please provide a stacktrace.

Comment: "*it is not working*" is neither a valid MySQL error message nor a valid Java exception.

Comment: `But when I am trying to connect with server` what does that mean here. If you want remote connection enter its IP instead of localhost

Answer (score 0):

It seems your example above is a little incorrect. Both point to the localhost domain, but your problem is probably related to the fact that your database by default does not allow remote connections for that specific username + db combination.

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE foo;
mysql> GRANT ALL ON foo.* TO bar@'192.168.1.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope i do not misinterpret the question, soley refering to the title: how to connect to mysql from within a jsp.

there are different options: let the connection handle the container/app-server or doing it on the fly in the jsp. as i understood, you want to connect from the jsp, so try something like this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>

<html>
<head>
<title>SELECT Operation</title>
</head>
<body>

<sql:setDataSource var="db" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/foobar"
     user="root"  password="12345"/>

<sql:query dataSource="${db}" var="result">
SELECT * from Employees;
</sql:query>
```

there happend some things:

- import the right taglibs
- place the driver in a reacheable position like WEB-INF\libs

you can browse the result later with a `<c:forEach>`